# Como pegar valor do Input e fazer uma conta

Tags: javascript, html, value

Olá, sou novo na área de programação, e estou aprendendo javascript. Decidi fazer uma ferramente que calculasse o AMA (abate, morte, assistência) de um jogo que jogo. A conta é somar os abates com as assistências e dividir pelas mortes. Até aí tudo bem. Fiz uma página usando bootstrap, e agora quero conseguir pegar o valor colocado lá, para fazer a conta, e eu não sei. Colocarei algumas partes do código aqui.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md">
            <p>Digite o número de abates</p>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Abates</span>
                </div>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="abates" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md">
            <p>Digite o número de mortes</p>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Mortes</span>
                </div>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="mortes" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md">
            <p>Digite o número de assistências</p>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Assistências</span>
                </div>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="assistencias" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
            </div>
            <br>

            <button onclick="calcularAma()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="botao-calcular">Calcular</button>
        </div>
        </div>
```

essa é uma parte do html. Aqui fica minha dúvida, como pegar o valor do input e calcular? Desculpem, eu pesquisei, mas não consegui achar no google. Estou totalmente perdido.

```
var abates = document.getElementById('abates');
var mortes = document.getElementById('mortes');
var assistencias = document.getElementById('assistencias');

var resultado;

function calcularAma(){
document.getElementById('abates').value;
document.getElementById('mortes').value;
document.getElementById('assistencias').value;
}
```

(caso precisem, eu colo o código inteiro no pastebin. Obrigado)

Comment: Faltou o básico: os inputs da morte e do abacate 

Comment: Perdão, eu fico perdido no que colar. Sabe como é, gente nova nesse negócio :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode fazer desta forma, convertendo apenas o que for somado para `parseInt`:

```js
function calcularAma(){
   var abates = parseInt(document.getElementById('abates').value);
   var mortes = document.getElementById('mortes').value;
   var assistencias = parseInt(document.getElementById('assistencias').value);
   
   var resultado = (abates+assistencias) / mortes;

   console.log(resultado);   
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md">
      <p>Digite o número de abates</p>
      <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Abates</span>
          </div>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="abates" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md">
      <p>Digite o número de mortes</p>
      <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Mortes</span>
          </div>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="mortes" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
      </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-md">
      <p>Digite o número de assistências</p>
      <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Assistências</span>
          </div>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="assistencias" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
      </div>
      <br>

      <button onclick="calcularAma()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="botao-calcular">Calcular</button>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!! Eu realmente tava confuso em como fazer isso! Acho que assim vou aprendendo aos poucos! Obrigado mesmo, abraços!

Comment: Já começou bem! Obg!